# Import JSON data to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am still pretty new to this--go easy on me please!

I have a JSON file `restaurant_list.json` that contains this information:

```
[{
  "objectID": 116272,
  "food_type": "Steak",
  "stars_count": 4.2,
  "reviews_count": 204,
  "neighborhood": "Pepper Pike",
  "_geoloc": {"lat": 41.153419, "lng": -81.864608},
   ...},
etc.
etc.
]
```

I created a `Restaurant` model in Rails that has identical column names to try and make this data import easy. I have tried various `serialize` and `JSON.parse()` methods used in other Stack Overflow answers with no success.

**How do I get this data into my Rails database?**

(Note: I am using the Rails standard SQLite for my database)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do like this in rails console or create rake task:

```
restaurant_list = JSON.parse(File.read('restaurant_list.json'))

restaurant_list.each do |restaurant|
  Restaurant.create(restaurant.to_h)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the first line in the rails console and got this error back: `JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at ',`

Comment: Figured out the JSON error. I had to change the format of the file. After that, your answer worked perfectly :)